# Why is passing parameters with navigation-rules not working in this case?

Tags: jsf, redirect, navigation, parameter-passing

So I have this sample code:

**hello.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{blahBlah.username}" />
    <br />
    <h:commandButton action="#{blahBlah.verifyUser()}" value="Go to goodbye!"/>
</h:form>
```

**BlahBlah.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BlahBlah {
    private String username;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String verifyUser(){
        if (!username.equals("koray")) {
            return "hello?faces-redirect=true&msg=" + username;
        }
        return "goodbye?faces-redirect=true&msg=" + username;
    }
}
```

and finally **goodbye.xhtml**

```
<f:view>
    <h:body>
        #{param.msg}
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

so this works as expected. Once I submit the form, I will find myself in

```
/goodbye.xhtml?msg=koray
```

etc..

But I want to use navigation-rules so this is how I modify my code:

**faces-config.xml**

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/hello.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/goodbye.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect>
            <redirect-param>
                <name>msg</name>
                <value>#{blahBlah.username}</value>
            </redirect-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/hello.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect>
            <redirect-param>
                <name>msg</name>
                <value>#{blahBlah.username}</value>
            </redirect-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

and

**BlahBlah.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BlahBlah {
    private String username;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String verifyUser(){
        if (!username.equals("koray")) {
            return "fail";
        }
        return "success";
    }
}
```

In this case, I will again be redirected to **goodbye.xhtml** but without the part **?msg=**

So what is the purpose of

```
<redirect-param>
    <name>msg</name>
    <value>#{blahBlah.username}</value>
</redirect-param>
```

and why is it not working?

Comment: Don't know the purpose, but its an exemplary question :-)